# MongoDB findAndModify update needed error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I can't think of a simpler use case for findAndModify.....

```
db.collection('products').findAndModify(
         { 
           query: { _id: new o_id(cart[i]._id) }, 
           update: { $inc: { sold: qty, onstock: (-1*qty) } }, 
           new: true 
   },function(e,d) { 
        if ( e ) return console.log('findAndModify error',e); 
});
```

But the above consistently returns the following error..

```
{ 
     [ MongoError: need remove or update ]
     name: 'MongoError',
     message: 'need remove or update',
     ok: 0,
     errmsg: 'need remove or update'
}
```

Am I missing something?

Also tried as suggested in Answer from zangw

```
db.collection('products').findAndModify(
        { _id: new o_id(cart[i]._id) },
        { $inc: { sold: qty, onstock: (-1*qty) } },
        { new: true },function(e,d) { 
            if ( e ) { return console.log('updateStock findAndModify error',e); }
            console.log('updated',d); 
        });
```

And now get another error

```
findAndModify error 
{ [MongoError: exception: nextSafe(): 
      { $err: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification",
        code: 17287 }]
   name: 'MongoError', message: 'exception: nextSafe(): 
  {  $err: "Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification", 
     code: 17287 
  }', 
     errmsg: 'exception: nextSafe(): 
  {  $err: "Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification", 
     code: 17287 }',
     code: 13106, 
     ok: 0 }
```

Am running MongoDB 2.6.11

SOLUTION, as suggested by @Blakes Seven (deprecation on findAndModify)

```
db.collection('products').findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new o_id(cart[i]._id) },
        { $inc: { sold: qty, onstock: (-1*qty) } },
function(e,d) { 
        if ( e ) { return console.log('updateStock findAndModify error',e); }
```

The findAndModify returns the updated document as d.value.

Answer (score 0):

Copy @Blacks comments as it

> there is a deprecation notice on the function ( has been for a couple of releases now ) and you should be using [.findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead.
>
> Noting the main difference in the `{ "returnOriginal": true }` option is now the default

---

Per [`findAndModify` doc](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify), the `findAndModify` is

```
findAndModify(query, sort, doc[, options], callback)
```

So please try this

```
db.collection('products').findAndModify(
           { _id: new o_id(cart[i]._id) }, 
           { _id:'descending'},
           { $inc: { sold: qty, onstock: (-1*qty) } }, 
           { new: true, upsert: true},
     function(e,d) { 
        if ( e ) return console.log('findAndModify error',e); 
});
```

Comment: Format you suggest failed, will update question with new tx's.

Comment: @user3094755, add `{_id:'descending'},` as my answer indicates

Comment: @user3094755 The `sort` is meant to be an "array", and is described as such in the documentation. You can just use `[]` for the default order. At any rate, there is a deprecation notice on the function ( has been for a couple of releases now ) and you should be using [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead. Noting the main difference in the `{ "returnOriginal": true }` option is now the default. And also renamed.